# QBXML components have not been installed

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml, qbwc

I have a user who is having a issues running a QuickBooks Web Connector service.

> Version:
>   1.2
>   Message:
>   Application requested to abort
>   Description:
>   Error connecting to QuickBooks. Error message received from QuickBooks was . Application has sent back a DONE via
>   connectionError. More information in available in the log file (click View Log button
>   from main window). Update aborted per request from application.

This is his log:

> QuickBooks Web Connector 2.1.0.30 has started.
>   Tuesday, June 11, 2013 at 5:24:37 PM
>   20130611.21:24:37 UTC : QBWebConnector_Load() : QBWC Form Loaded
>   20130611.21:24:46 UTC : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() :         updateWS() for application = 'HunterInvoices' has STARTED
>   20130611.21:24:46 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.getUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock = FALSE
>   20130611.21:24:46 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to True
>   20130611.21:24:46 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ******************** Update session locked ********************
>   20130611.21:24:47 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.
>   20130611.21:24:47 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: HunterInvoices
>   20130611.21:24:47 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): HunterInvoices
>   20130611.21:24:47 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: https://srv-iweb-01.hunter.com/HunterInvoices/HunterInvoices.asmx
>   20130611.21:24:47 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().
>   20130611.21:24:48 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : Received from serverVersion() following parameter:
>   20130611.21:24:48 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:
>   20130611.21:24:48 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : Received from clientVersion() following parameter:
>   20130611.21:24:48 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application agrees with the current version of QBWebConnector. Allowing update operation.
>   20130611.21:24:48 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'HunterInvoices', username = '360030'
>   20130611.21:24:48 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:
>   20130611.21:24:49 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.updateWS() : Received from authenticate() following parameters:
>   20130611.21:24:49 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setCurrentWebServiceName() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\CurrentWebServiceName has been set to HunterInvoices
>   20130611.21:24:49 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setCurrentWebServiceSessionTicket() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\CurrentWebServiceSessionTicket has been set to ddd359af-cc10-4002-a678-4f350567cdf2
>   20130611.21:24:49 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.CheckCFNResponse() : User authenticated.
>   20130611.21:24:49 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Done.
>   20130611.21:24:49 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.OpenConnection() : Connecting to QuickBooks...
>   20130611.21:24:49 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.handleAllOtherError() : QBWC1013: Error connecting to QuickBooks. Returning error message to application.
>   Unexpected error. Check the "qbsdklog.txt" file for possible additional information.
>   20130611.21:24:49 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_connectionError() : *** Calling connectionError() with following parameters:
>   20130611.21:24:49 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_connectionError() : Received from connectionError() following parameters:
>   20130611.21:24:49 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.OpenConnection() : Error connecting to QuickBooks. Application sent back DONE. Job ending.
>   20130611.21:24:49 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
>   20130611.21:24:49 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ******************** Update session unlocked ********************
>   20130611.21:24:49 UTC : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : Update completed with errors. See log (QWClog.txt) for details.

And here are the contents of qbsdklog.txt

> 20130611.173436 I 4244 RequestProcessor ========= Started Connection =========
>   20130611.173436 I 4244 RequestProcessor Request Processor, QBXMLRP2 v12.0
>   20130611.173436 I 4244 RequestProcessor Connection opened by app named 'HunterInvoices'
>   20130611.173436 I 4244 CertVerifier The Authenticode signature validated OK.
>   20130611.173436 I 4244 RequestProcessor OS: Microsoft Windows Vista Home Basic Edition Service Pack 1 (build 6001), 32-bit
>   20130611.173436 I 4244 RequestProcessor Current User is in AdminGroup
>   20130611.173436 I 4244 RequestProcessor Current Process Integrity Level : 2000
>   20130611.173436 I 4244 RequestProcessor Getting the IUnknown COM instance of QB
>   20130611.173436 I 4244 RequestProcessor Opening the file in the DoNotCare mode.
>   20130611.173436 E 4244 RequestProcessor Process Request error = 80042505, QBXML components have not been installed.
>   20130611.173436 E 4244 RequestProcessor Process Request error = 80042505, QBXML components have not been installed.
>   20130611.173436 E 4244 RequestProcessor Process Request error = 80042505, QBXML components have not been installed.
>   20130611.173436 E 4244 RequestProcessor Process Request error = 80042505, QBXML components have not been installed.
>   20130611.173436 E 4244 RequestProcessor Unable to process Host Query request.
>   20130611.173436 I 4244 RequestProcessor Connection closed by app named 'HunterInvoices'
>   20130611.173436 I 4244 RequestProcessor ========== Ended Connection ==========

We've already tried renaming the .TLG file and that didn't help.  I've seen some suggest that this error is ultimately due to a corrupted file in QB itself, and the only resolution is the uninstall/reinstall QuickBooks.  Is this the only way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Before you try anything, try running the QuickBooks updates, and then rebooting the computer.

If that fails, re-install QuickBooks, as it's likely a corrupt installation of QuickBooks.

Comment: What version of QB and what release. As Keith suggested make sure you have applied all updates.

Comment: He's running 2013 Pro.  I will have him make sure he's up to date and try again.